# Does the lack of tonsils make pronouncing french sounds harder?

Tags: french, trills, rhotics

I've had my tonsils removed a long time ago. I'm facing difficulty in pronouncing some sounds that start in throat like the french R. Does the lack of tonsils make it impossible for me produce the correct sound?

Comment: The air comes up from the throat but the sound is not in the throat.

Comment: simple past is better: I had my tonsils removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the tonsils aren't involved in the production of a voiced uvular fricative (what is the linguistic term for the French r). So, even without tonsils most people can produce this sound. Tonsil extraction is a frequent surgical treatment and does not cause speech impediments (usually, rare effects may be there or not, I have no information on that).

EDIT: In the first writing, I assumed that the French r were an uvular trill—it nowadays usually isn't. The [Wikipedia article Guttural R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttural_R) has an overview on different realisations of the guttural r.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the French rhotic is rarely classified as a uvular trill like you say. I believe that uvular approximants and fricatives are more common than trills in France.